# How to get latest record from database category wise?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table named images

here it is :

```
+------------------+---------------+----------------------+
| iid |  category  |   imagename   |       uploaddate     |
+------------------+---------------+----------------------+
|  1  |    cat1    |    123.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:01  |
|  2  |    cat2    |    456.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:02  |
|  3  |    cat2    |    789.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:03  |
|  4  |    cat3    |    001.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:04  |
|  5  |    cat3    |    002.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:05  |
|  6  |    cat3    |    002.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:06  |
|  7  |    cat4    |    004.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:07  |
|  8  |    cat4    |    005.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:08  |
|  9  |    cat4    |    006.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:09  |
|  10 |    cat4    |    007.png    | 2013-01-01 01:01:10  |
+------------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

Now I want to retrieve images category wise. it means get image from each category at once and with descending order by uploaddate.

please do not suggest : `SELECT * FROM images GROUP BY category ORDER BY uploaddate DESC`
Because I use pagination to display that images and each page contain distinct images from distinct category.

I solved this but there is alternative way to solve it...
Here My solution :

=> Find all distinct category and save it in array.

=> Iterate for loop and get images from that particular category.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($distinctcat);$i++)
    {
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE category = '".$distinctcat."'";
        // fetch that data then save it in to array
    }
```

=> arrange images datewise.

=> cut array using array_slice function according to our pagination limit and page number

Can any one suggest me better solution or single query that handle all that things...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question is asked several times a day in SO.

Answer (score 3):

The following query will get all latest image for every category,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    images a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  category, MAX(uploaddate) max_date
            FROM    images
            GROUP   BY category
        ) b ON a.category = b.category AND
                a.uploadDate = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803e1/1)

but if you want for specific `category` only, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    images a
WHERE   category = 'categoryName'
ORDER   BY uploadDate DESC
LIMIT   1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803e1/3)

Comment: I have heard about SQL Fiddle today. It is awesome.